# Read file in android - file permission denied

Tags: android, filesystems

I want to read file from external storage. I uploaded the file in Eclipse DDMS to storage/sdcard (image below). But whenever I tried to read, I got an error of permission denied. Is there any problem in my file permission? Or I need to add anything in manifest file (I am not writing anything at the moment)?

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Folder Tree]

**Code:**

```
public void extimport(View v){
   EditText xedittxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.frmexttxt);
   String xedit = xedittxt.getText().toString();
   xedit = xedit.trim();
   File file;
   file = new File(xedit);
   StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
   Log.d("fcheck",""+xedit);
   try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); //THIS LINE THROWS ERROR
      Log.d("fcheck","f3"); //This line never got printed
      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         text.append(line);
         text.append('\n');
      }
      br.close();
      resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);
      resultView.setText(text);
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
      Log.d("File open error",""+e);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error opening the file.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
11-19 00:21:54.252: D/fcheck(5885): /storage/sdcard/mylibman.csv
11-19 00:21:54.272: D/File open error(5885): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/mylibman.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: you need to add readexternalstorge permission.

Comment: add external storage read permission in manifest file

Comment: oh .. my apology .. I never thought reading would require any permission, hence didn't even googled it, rather focused on file permission system during google search! .. my mistake :( ..... and thanks a lot for pointing it out

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Make sure you have added the permission to read external storage in your manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Not work with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in manifest

Answer (score 6):

I was experiencing the same problem and it can be easily removed by following either of these steps:
1. Install your app by using -g if installing on Android N and O versions.
2. Grant permission manually
 Settings->apps->"app_name"->Permissions->Enable Switch

For Both steps 1 and 2, define uses-permission

```
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in AndroidManifest.xml
```

Like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="...">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- all permissions here -->
    <application
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Storage permission needs to be given by the user before accessing the functionality

**Add Dependency:**

```
dependencies:
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
      var status = await Permission.storage.status;
       if (status.isUndetermined) {
            // You can request multiple permissions at once.
            Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
              Permission.storage,
            ].request();
            print(statuses[Permission.storage]); // it should print PermissionStatus.granted
          }
```