# Can't send image in my application to external app as implicit intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new to android i have read mant aricles on this from stackoverflow and other resources but i tried my best to get result
At time of sending i select gmail to send my image but its showing empty file cant be attached
i tried with different images in my package but i get the same response
Here is my code which i tried

```
    Intent intent;     
   Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                        "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.cursor)
                        + '/' + getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.cursor) + '/' +
                        getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.cursor) );
                intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select app to send");
                startActivity(chooser);
```

Comment: Few Android apps will be expecting `android.resource` as a `Uri` scheme.

Comment: ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE this adds android.resource to Uri

Comment: Correct. And few Android activities supporting `ACTION_SEND` will expect to see that scheme. You will have better luck copying your resource to a file, then using `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` for sharing.

Comment: am fresh to android so i cant understand you can you tell it briefly

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content

Comment: i have already read this but its problem with Uri

Comment: "i have already read this" -- then read it again and follow the instructions. The two bullets explain your options for sharing the content. Using the `android.resource` scheme is not one of those options.

Comment: i am asking can you help to find a solution, i have read it and i didn't find any solution

Comment: I pointed out the solution: You will have better luck copying your resource to a file, then using `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` for sharing. The documentation that I cited also suggested using `FileProvider`. `FileProvider` has [its own documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) explaining how to use it.

Comment: thats what i dosent know sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
options.outMimeType = "image/jpeg";

Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher, options);

String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Image Description", null);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: getDrawable() is deprecated so app crashes

Comment: still not working this is what i see in logcat  E/MediaStore: File creation failed
                                                                              java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063957/read-file-in-android-file-permission-denied. Add the permission suggested in this article in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: sir if this image were jpg file what changes should i make

Comment: intent.setType("image/jpeg"); is set to jpg but in your question you specify that any image type can be used: intent.setType("image/*");

Comment: sir how can i take a jpg image from drawable for this purpose

Comment: sir when i tray jpeg image it still shows same error, i have edited code can you check it

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, finally one more doubt sir whats error with my code sir, i got it from android tutorials

Comment: @CommonsWare is correct : "Few Android apps will be expecting android.resource as a Uri" (ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE). This solution takes your resource file and saves it to the MediaStore then other apps can reference this file. Both this solution and CommonsWare's solution is described in this: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content